Error on build Flutter project with IntelliJ/Android Studio
I'm having a problem running the newly created flutter project. When creating a project following: New > Project
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:compileClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I found some things on the internet but nothing really worked.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.22.3 on channel stable at /Users/tiagopaza/Documents/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0850beeb2 (7 days ago), 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 235db911ba
    • Dart version 3.4.4
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tiagopaza/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.12+0)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 80.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 241.18808

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

I know it's something in my development environment because when I create the project on another computer it does the build. I think it's something to do with AGP, but when I click on the tab it doesn't even open.
On a coworker's machine, when I open the Flutter project in the android directory, the tab to update the AGP version appears, but mine doesn't even appear because of the error: Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0 appears before.
Note: The build.gradle file is in the new format without the buildscript
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


For creating new flutter project use: New > New Flutter Project, if you don't find that option then make sure you have installed flutter and dart plugin in plugins

Sorry for my mistake, but it's through the New > New Flutter Project

Solved by myself, the problem is related to Flutter SDK. Just delete the folder and download stable SDK version from official project.
